# How to use memray with Gunicorn and Django?

Tags: python, django, memory-management, memory-leaks, gunicorn

I have a project with Django and I did a multiread with Gunicorn. but my project has a memory leak. I want to monitor memory with "[memray](https://github.com/bloomberg/memray/)" but I don't know how to use "[memray](https://github.com/bloomberg/memray/)".

Answer (score 3):

During local development, I've had success by running:

```sh
python -m memray run manage.py runserver 0:8000 --nothreading
```

I haven't had memray running in production yet, but memray's documentation does mention `--follow-fork` may be useful when using Gunicorn.

> Memray can optionally continue tracking in a child process after a parent process forks. This can be useful when using multiprocessing, or a framework utilizing a pre-fork pattern like Celery or Gunicorn.
>
> https://bloomberg.github.io/memray/run.html#tracking-across-forks

Comment: --nothreading is not a valid option for me

Comment: @lmaooooo, `--nothreading` is an option of django's `runserver` command (not of memray). Perhaps you're using a different command?